# Where did the awesome questions-in-review counter on the tag page go?

Tags: feature-request, review, tags-page

For a while, there was a little orange badge on the bottom-right of tag wiki excerpts that would show how many of the posts in that tag were currently in review.

I thought this was awesome and want it back. Plz?

Comment: There are no items for you to review matching the filter...oh wait...

Comment: My guess: they've watched usage patterns and found very few people clicked it. Did they recently add the "[tag] jobs" link to SO? That may have replaced it

Comment: @mhlester "[tag] jobs" has been around for quite a lot longer.

Comment: Ok thanks @michaelb958, I must have somehow just always missed it